# Dag Site SecurityQA getMFAResponseForSite returning errorCode 522 even with correct answers

Tags: yodlee

I'm attempting to follow the provided add site flow with the DAG dummy accounts and the MFA flow for siteId 16486 (Security QA) always returns a 522 regardless of the answers provided to the questions.

Here's an outline of the API calls I'm making with their responses.

1. **addSiteAccount1**

`{
      "siteAccountId":11070119,
      "isCustom":false,
      "credentialsChangedTime":1425920373,
      "siteRefreshInfo":{
        "siteRefreshStatus":{
          "siteRefreshStatusId":1,
          "siteRefreshStatus":"REFRESH_TRIGGERED"
        },
        "siteRefreshMode":{
          "refreshModeId":1,
          "refreshMode":"MFA"
        },
        "updateInitTime":1425920374,
        "nextUpdate":1425921274,
        "code":801,
        "suggestedFlow":{
          "suggestedFlowId":2,
          "suggestedFlow":"REFRESH"
        },
        "noOfRetry":0
      },
      "siteInfo":{
        "popularity":0,
        "siteId":16486,
        "orgId":1148,
        "defaultDisplayName":"Dag Site SecurityQA",
        "defaultOrgDisplayName":"Demo Bank",
        "enabledContainers":[
          {
            "containerName":"bank",
            "assetType":1
          }
        ],
        "baseUrl":"http://192.168.210.152:9090/dag/dhaction.do",
        "loginForms":[
        ],
        "isHeld":false,
        "isCustom":false,
        "mfaType":{
          "typeId":4,
          "typeName":"SECURITY_QUESTION"
        },
        "siteSearchVisibility":true,
        "isAlreadyAddedByUser":true,
        "isOauthEnabled":false
      },
      "created":"2015-03-09T09:59:33-0700",
      "retryCount":0
    }`

2. **getMFAResponseForSite**

`{
      "isMessageAvailable":true,
      "fieldInfo":{
        "questionAndAnswerValues":[
          {
            "question":"What is the name of your state?",
            "questionFieldType":"label",
            "responseFieldType":"text",
            "isRequired":"true",
            "sequence":1,
            "metaData":"QUESTION_1"
          },
          {
            "question":"What is the name of your first school",
            "questionFieldType":"label",
            "responseFieldType":"text",
            "isRequired":"true",
            "sequence":2,
            "metaData":"QUESTION_2"
          }
        ],
        "numOfMandatoryQuestions":-1
      },
      "timeOutTime":99060,
      "itemId":0,
      "memSiteAccId":11070119,
      "retry":false
    }`

3. **putMFAResponseForSite**

`{ 
      "primitiveObj":true
    }`

4. **getMFAResponseForSite**

`{
      "isMessageAvailable":false,
      "timeOutTime":150000,
      "itemId":0,
      "errorCode":522,
      "memSiteAccId":11070119,
      "retry":false
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It turns out that my parameters for the call to putMFAResponseForSite were invalid.

Comment: hello @Drew i'm stuck with the same response "522", what parameters was invalid? thanks